# Format an Integer as a number in VisualForce page

Tags: visualforce, formatting

I am trying to format the field BodyLength of the Attachment Object which is an Integer in my VisualForce Page.
This should work but it doesn't.

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,###,###,###}">
    <apex:param value="{!att.BodyLength} kb"/>
</apex:outputText>
```

I got the following error message:

> The value attribute on  is not in a valid format. It
>   must be a positive number, and of type Number, Date, Time, or Choice.

Any idea how to format an integer as a number or any other solution?
Thank you in advance for your help.
Sylvie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of providing the unit at the param, provide it at the outputText and it should work.

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,###,###,### kb}">
    <apex:param value="{!myint}"/>
</apex:outputText>
```

Comment: +1 was trying to remember this